# DDD: Where to put logic in aggregation root

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design

Still experimenting with DDD and have some doubts, maybe someone would help me.

Lets say that I have 2 models:

```
public class Event
{
    User Creator;
    List<User> Members;
}

public class User {}
```

My problem is that I cannot see place for logic that I want to implement. I need 3 actions:

- User join event
- User leave event
- Creator remove user from event (only Creator can remove users)

For now I just created domain service *EventUserService* that calls *Event.RemoveUser/AddUser* and ie. checks if *CurrentUser* (provided by *UserService*) is creator of event (have rights to remove other users).
Maybe that approach is ok, but I still feel that I should putt that logic into aggregation roots, ie. :

- User.JoinEvent(Event) - i can add passed Event to User.Events collection (bidirectionall) base on some logic.
- User.LeaveEvent(Event) - analogous to JoinEvent.
- User.RemoveUserFromEvent(User,Event) - I can have *CreatedEvents* collection in *User* and for *Event* from that collection I can call *Event.RemoveUser(User)* - this way I will make sure that only creator can kick someone.
  Or
- Evet.RemoveUser(UserToRemove) - but how I will make sure that its called by creator ?

If first two method looks ok (at least for me), 3rd one would create *Event.RemoveUser* (to manage Event members collection) method that could be used to bypass logic residing in *User.RemoveUserFromEvent*.

So, in the end I have 2 questions:

1. What is your approach in situation like this where two aggregation roots works together and one operation is determine by logic residing in both of them? Maybe some kind of methoods like *User.CanJoinEvent(Event)* ?
2. What about creating "danger" point like *User.RemoveUserFromEvent*

Maybe someone can putt a little bit light on that for me, every help would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Event
{
    User Creator;
    List<User> Members;
}
```

Don't do that. You are breaking Law Of Demeter and the `Event` class has no control over the changes in `Members` or the users in that list. You should instead define methods in the `Event` class which is used to handle the members.

Now, if you do that change, i.e. have something like this:

```
public class Event
{
    User Creator { get private set; }
    bool IsMember(string name);
    void AddMember(User user);
}
```

You'll suddenly have solid places to generate the events.

> but how I will make sure that its called by creator ?

In .NET you can use `Thread.CurrentPrinicpal` to get information about the logged in user. It do however require that you implement your own `IPrincipal`/`IIdentity`.

Remember: You should ALWAYS make sure that the models are in a valid state in DDD. That usually means that all setters should be private: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/06/protect-your-data/

Comment: Thx for answer. After posting that question I was more thinking towards solution that u gave me, about responsibilities and law that u mentioned. Still have small doubt about current user - isn't that more a part of infrastructure then domain ? But if it is like that - so how handle logic that depend on current user ? Pass current user as argument and "believe" that this is current, not any other, user? In my case I was thinking about passing service by argument to method instead of using some  static property.

Comment: yes. Using a service and passing the current user is a better solution. but imho, IIdentity/IPrincipal is in .NET and easy to adjust. I use it in my applications when validating stuff.